# using if with scope on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to make a named scope called :current_season where the it will correctly identify the records associated with the year we are in.  Mostly easy enough except I want everything June and later to use the current year and everything prior to June to use the previous year.

in rails 3.1  I can easily use:

```
scope :current_season, lambda { where('season = ?',Time.now.year) } if Time.now.month >= 6
```

to get the scope to only work if we are at the end of the year and :

```
scope :current_season, lambda { where('season = ?',Time.now.year - 1) } if Time.now.month < 6
```

But it seems to wasteful to have to name it all twice and not use an if/else type of thing or be able to call in something I define below to show the exact year such as:

```
scope :current_season, lambda { where('season = ?',:current_season_year) } 

def current_season_year
  if Time.now.month >= 6
    Time.now.year
  else
    Time.now.year - 1
  end
end
```

But that just laughs at me when I try it.   Is there a cleaner way?  I will also have a scope :last_season and scope :previous_season most likely and they will follow similar logic.

thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Named scopes are just a DSL for writing a class methods that all have a similar functionality. Whenever you find them to be limiting you, just switch to a class method instead:

```
def self.current_season
  year = Time.now.month >= 6 ? Time.now.year : Time.now.year - 1
  where('season = ?', year)
end
```

Of course, you could also include that in a scope like this:

```
scope :current_season, do
  # same code as above...
end
```

It's just going to define it as a class method on the model though. The tradeoff is clarity in the intention of a scope (it's expected to return a chainable `ActiveRecord::Relation`) versus clarity in documentation (if you run something like RDoc it isn't going to notice a method available at `Model.current_season` because it hasn't been defined in the code yet).

#### Update:

There is one additional benefit from using a scope instead of a class method:

```
User.admin.create name: 'Corey'  #=> <User: @name="Corey" @admin=true>
```

You can use a scope to *create* an object with certain parameters, as well. In this case, this isn't very useful, but it's worth considering when deciding which to use.

Comment: Ah... so THAT'S how that works.  Excellent. And we can string those together as well like: `Donation.current_season.bigger_than_1k.paid_by_check.whatever_else_i_want`  Thanks very much!